# Why CSS media query work in wrong manner?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm new in CSS, especially with media queries.
I've added this to my header tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and this in my body

```
<img id="title" class="title" src="image/ti.jpg" >
```

and at the end in my CSS file

```css
@media screen and (max-width : 570px){
 .title{
    width: 80%;  
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I use device mode in Chrome developer tools, this code works fine, but when I change the size of explorer instead of operating in

```
width=570px
```

It happens in 160px.

Comment: Internet Explorer might not support something here

Comment: Your question is a little unclear -- you're saying that your media query breakpoint triggers at `570px` in Chrome, but `160px` in IE? Have you recently set the breakpoint as `160px`? Have you cleared your IE cache (with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`)?

Comment: @ObsidianAge tnx for your answer and apologies for my unclear question, in fact, I didn't say the IE, my idea was chrome browser when I change the width of my browser the media applied in 160px but I define 570px, it is my problem

Comment: `.title` will be `width: 80%;` between `0px` and `570px`. Sounds like you're expecting `width: 80%;` to be applied above `570px`.

Comment: @hungerstar  the problem is that it works in firefox correctly but in chrome, it is not. I mean when I change the width of the browser.

Comment: Nobody knows what _"works correctly"_ is at this point, hence the lack of answers. This question, when presented properly, should be solved rather quickly. Please confirm what you expect to happen below `570px` and what you expect to happen above `570px`.

Comment: I don't know how  I should declare my question, I want that the width of .titie element become 80 percent when the width of the browser goes below the 570px, it works in firefox but in chrome, title's width changing happens when the browser width is160 px, it means it happens in 160 px instead of 570px, I don't know what is wrong with my code, I thought maybe something is in the chrome that causes this problem and somebody has seen that before